# Bash script error with exponent expression

Tags: linux, bash

i'm writting a script with an outer loop and two inner loop, i must not be correctly typing out the syntax but i want to write an expression for my first inner loop where i raise $2 to the power of j + 1: $2^(j+1)

This is not a complete script:

```
    for((d=0;d<=($2**($j+1));d++)) <----
do

done
```

What is the proper way to write such an expression in a for loop?

Comment: Your syntax works just fine for me, assuming that `$2` and `$j` have been initialized properly. What values do you have for `$2` and `$j`?

Comment: I concur with @ruakh, your error is not on this line. I recommend debugging with `set -x`.

Comment: this is the outer loop of the inner loop
for((j=0;j<=$1-1;j++))
$1 and $2 are set in the terminal, they are 3 and 4

The terminal says: line 8:syntax error near ';d++))'
line 8: 'for ((d=0;d<=($2**($j+1);d++))'

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
for((d=0;d<=$(($2**($j+1)));d++)) <----
```

`$` sign and double `((` around the expression.

Depends a bit on the `bash` version you are using. Sometimes you don't need the `$`...